# Can I insert audio in flv file at a specific location using actionscript3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-media-server

I've a flash AS3 based application that provides option to play/pause/record FLV files from flash media server. These files are only audio files. Now, I want to add a new functionality of inserting audio at a specific location.

Like if the already recorded file is of five minutes duration, and I want to record 1 minute audio after third minute, the end result should be a six minute file with the new audio added from 3rd to 4th minute.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done on the server side. Using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), convert the FLV to WAV, then using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) you can take a WAV file, split it and then concatenate it to another WAV file. Finally, using ffmpeg, you can encode it back to FLV.

Working directly with the flv files (without converting it back and forth) might also be possible using [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/), but I'm not sure.